# Notification is not getting Cancelled

Tags: android, android-notifications

**Before saying anything please read whole question first.**

Here is my code for creating a notification:-

```
public void showNotification(String Name, String Rate, int Image_Source, int PandP, int Repeat) {

    remoteview = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
    context = this;
    pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(this, SongsListActivity.class), 0);
    P_and_P_I = new Intent("P_and_P_Clicked");
    R_I = new Intent("R_Clicked");
    N_I = new Intent("N_Clicked");
    P_I = new Intent("P_Clicked");
    P_and_P_PI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, P_and_P_I, 0);
    R_PI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, R_I, 0);
    N_PI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 3, N_I, 0);
    P_PI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 4, P_I, 0);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContent(remoteview)
            .setPriority(2)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setTicker(NameD.getText())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(NameD.getText())
            .setContentText(RateD.getText())
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setCustomBigContentView(remoteview)
            .build();


    remoteview.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.P_and_P_N, P_and_P_PI);
    remoteview.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Repeat_N, R_PI);
    remoteview.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Next_N, N_PI);
    remoteview.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Previous_N, P_PI);
    remoteview.setImageViewResource(R.id.Repeat_N, Repeat);
    remoteview.setImageViewResource(R.id.P_and_P_N, PandP);
    remoteview.setTextViewText(R.id.Name_N, Name);
    remoteview.setTextViewText(R.id.Rate_N, Rate);
    remoteview.setImageViewResource(R.id.Image_N, Image_Source);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(111111, notification);


}
```

I try to cancel the notification by calling this method:-

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
    if(mediaplayer != null)
    {
        mediaplayer.release();
        mediaplayer = null;
        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

**I use this showNotification several times in the code.**
**I am sure that onDestroy is being called.**

In the begining, when the showNotification is called only once, and then if the app is being destroyed, the notification **gets cancelled**, but when showNotification gets called several times, even twice, then on destroying the app, it doesn't gets cancelled.

**all variables are public throughout the program for all methods.**

and yeah, their is only one notification being showed which gets updated everytime when i call showNotification.

What should i do so that the notification gets cancelled even if the  method gets called several times?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that is happening, but have you tried the following to troubleshoot?

Try moving the `cancelAll()` into the `onPause()` and see if it works there.

Try grabbing the reference to the notification manager again in the `onDestory()`

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Try a cancel with the notification ID instead `cancel(111111)`

Just a suggestion, you should check to see if the notificationManager is null in the onDestory().  If a notification was never showing, it will throw a null pointer and any code afterwards will never run.

**Update**

If your app is APU 18 or greater, you can check to see if you have any active notifications before you attempt to post it again:

[getActiveNotifications()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications())

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms. My problem turned out to be that I was calling `showNotification` on a sensor Event. These events triggered new notifications between `cancelAll` and the end of `onDestroy`.

The solution for me was to create a class-wide boolean `stahp` and only show the notification if `!stahp`. I set `stahp` to `true` before calling `cancelAll`